# Чем обосновать постановку запятой перед частицей "да"?

Tags: частица

> Он не может, да и не стремится скрыть ненависть к отцу...

Чем можно обосновать запятую перед ***да***?

Answer (score 1):

***Он не может, да и не стремится скрыть ненависть...***

***ДА И*** — присоединительный союз (частица ***ДА*** входит в его состав).

В то же время союз ***ДА И*** многозначен: он может иметь **соединительное** значение, а также используется в устойчивых сочетаниях. Этот материал изложен у Розенталя (п. 5):  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

Поэтому каждый раз приходится определять значение союза ***ДА И***.

В приведенном предложении союз имеет **присоединительное значение**, запятая перед ним ставится.

В то же время это не совсем стандартная конструкция, так как союз относится к **вспомогательным глаголам**. Поэтому присоединяемое сказуемое не обособляется, а только отделяется запятой. Союз ***ДА И*** по значению здесь скорее соответствует двойному союзу ***НЕ ТОЛЬКО ... НО И***.

Обычно присоединяемый член предложения **обособляется с двух сторон:**  *Он не создал, **да и не мог создать**, ни одного крупного произведения. В этом взгляде, **да и во всём поведении Лидии**, явилось нечто новое.*

Comment: Почему всё-таки вы не отбиваете пробелом вторые части союзов? Режет глаз очень, но, может, вы правильно делаете, хочется уяснить этот момент.

Comment: Чем этот пример отличается от следующего на Грамоте: *Поехал в город да и не вернулся*? http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_151

Comment: Артем, я за Грамоту.ру не в ответе, мне Розенталь как-то ближе (но у него тоже есть похожий пример). Как я понимаю,  Вы не хотите в заданном предложении ставить запятую? Было бы хорошо, если бы Вы дали альтернативный ответ и обосновали свое решение.  Что касается "поехал да и не вернулся", то нет тут добавочной присоединительной информации, а частица ДА является скорее усилительной, то есть характерна для сказочных сюжетов или может придавать особую эмоциональность действию. Но это мое мнение, а Вы могли бы рассказать нам о своем понимании темы.

Comment: Да нет, я не считал, что не нужна запятая. Просто хотел получше понять Вашу мысль. Вроде теперь понимаю. А как насчёт многоточий? Мне кажется, надо отделять после и не надо перед (в этих случаях). Вы согласны?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему сказумое отделяется только с одной стороны?

Comment: @ Артём Луговой В учебнике у Кустовой (2013 год) пробел с двух сторон. Глубокого содержания в этих пробелах я не вижу (для меня это только лишь принятая условность обозначения), но всё-таки, наверное, запись должна быть симметричной.

Comment: @Владимир Он не может, да и не стремится СКРЫТЬ ненависть...  Нельзя совсем обособить вспомогательный глагол "не стремится", так как СКРЫТЬ  - это общий основной глагол для двух вспомогательных глаголов

Comment: Хм, а у Розенталя вообще без пробелов, как Вы и писали всегда. В общем, нигде мне не нравится. :((

Comment: Это чисто оформительская тема, она регулируется своими стандартами, просто надо найти современный вариант. Попробуйте задать вопрос на форуме.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь:

2. Если присоединительная конструкция тесно связана по смыслу с последующей частью высказывания и перед ней не предусмотрена пауза, то она может только отделяться запятой от предшествующей части предложения:

Это называется «экономический кризис», и трудно понять, как вывернутся, да и вывернутся ли предприниматели из этой петли (Газ.);

Поздно теперь, да и не к чему возвращаться к этому вопросу;

При проведении подобных сложных экспериментов трудно, да и невозможно избежать отдельных ошибок;